# "I truly believe no other sport builds a character as rowing (does)"

Tags: sentence

Is this sentence correct? With or without "does"? Any (better) alternatives?

Comment: No other sport builds character as much/well as rowing does.  No other sport is better at building character than rowing.  There is no better character-building sport than rowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this sentence as

> "I truly believe no other sport builds character like rowing."

Note that I've dropped the indefinite article "a" in front of *character*, since character here is a general noun describing an intangible thing, not describing *a* character like any particular person. I've also changed *as* to *like*. The inclusion or omission of *does* is optional, either way works.

Comment: Although it's not wrong to include 'a' even before the getting-on-for-non-count usage, as shorthand for 'a person's character', I'd agree that the dropping of the article would be more idiomatic here. However, dropping 'does' is not idiomatic here. I won't downvote, though; your alternative with 'like' is what most people would say (though even here, purists might challenge this usage of 'like'). And now, dropping the 'does' is quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to drop the `does` but the sentence feels more complete if you include it instead.

You can rephrase as :

> I truly believe no other sport builds character as does rowing

Comment: If you drop the _does_ you'll not sound like a natural speaker.

Comment: True. But that won't make the sentence incorrect.

Comment: I'd say it would. R. Quirk & J. Svartvik (eds.), in 'Investigating linguistic acceptability', argue for a five-point gradience approach to acceptability of individual sentences say. I've looked on the internet (30+ results) and found no examples where the 'does' has been dropped from 'as rowing [does]' (other than one 'as much as rowing'). And imagine dropping the 'does' in _this_: '... hot sauces stimulate the release of endorphins in the brain, just as exercise does.' Not 100% incorrect, but nowhere near 100% acceptable. 'Like' is used for 'in the [same] way that' in conversation nowadays.

Comment: Ah, maybe. But here, dropping the `does` doesn't make me uneasy like other incorrect sentences do. Either my engense is faulty or the sentence is indeed correct !

Comment: These things can get very opinion-based; I could say the same things, and perhaps list higher credentials. But there needs to be some support from recognised authority on ELU. You haven't offered any; [ODO thesaurus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/as) gives: _there were some who felt as Frank did_ and the definitions 'in the (same) way that, the (same) way, in the (same) manner that' (and you can't say 'in the same way that Frank.').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Call me a purist, but I truly dislike the use of 'like' (also, it is a rather formal text I am writing). Since you have mentioned the "as much as rowing" variant, which of these sound better: **"I truly believe no other sport builds character as rowing does"** or **"I truly believe no other sport builds character as much as rowing (does)"**? It may be important to note that I want this sentence to be emphasized, as it will begin a whole paragraph describing a career of a rower.

Comment: @ziu ... I'd use 'to the extent that' ('same' understood after 'no other sport'). But I'd certainly not use 'as rowing' without 'does' here.

Comment: (1) I've not tracked down 'engense'. (2) (a) "If you drop the 'does' you'll not sound like a natural speaker." / (b) "True." ... (c) "But here, dropping the 'does' doesn't make me uneasy." >> I think there's a problem.

Comment: (1) `engsense` is - "english sense" (like spidey-sense ?) (2) Not sounding like a natural speaker is not a bad thing, it's actually okay as long as your grammar is not incorrect - it doesn't make me uneasy because dropping `does` doesn't sound incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The original is a hybrid from two possible, legitimate constructions:

.1. *no sport like rowing* (compares a noun phrase with a noun)

If this is the construction you prefer, 'other' is redundant; and 'does' is ungrammatical.

> .1."**I truly believe no** other **sport builds character like rowing**."

.2. *builds character as rowing builds character*. (compares two verb phrases, formerly known as clauses, and requires the conjunction "as")

If this is the construction you prefer, use *as* not *like*, and *does* is not optional in formal use.

> .2."**I truly believe no** other **sport builds character as rowing does**."